Postgres data sync between different servers
I have 2 postgres clusters (A and B) on different servers. Whenever data is written to the table on server A, I want to copy the data to the table on server B.
But the data retention in the table on server A is only 1 month whereas the data needs to be retained for 1 year on server B. (The tables are partitioned)
How can I achieve this?

You can use logical replication for only the INSERT statements for this table. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/17/logical-replication.html for details

@FrankHeikens, I also want to replicate the updates and deletes. I only want to exclude the purging of old partitions. Is that possible via logical replication?

Yes, no problem. Drop table partition isn’t part of the replication. Just test it
